# What does 'export * from' means in Angular

Tags: angular

I cloned an app from github and found in the 'index.ts' file, it has the following entries:

```
export * from './auth.guard';
export * from './basic-auth.interceptor';
export * from './error.interceptor';
export * from './fake-backend';
```

What does 'export *' do in this case?

Comment: That's not Angular-specific, just ES6 modules; see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: The asterisk (*) is often used to describe a wildcard, which means that it will select everything possible. So this will export everything exported in the listed files, so that you need only to import index.ts instead of all of the files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to Angular only and such statements can be found in any ES6+ code. Actually the statements like

```
export * from './fake-backend'
```

will import all the functions available in the module and it is pretty handy than giving relative paths to  each file / module you want to export or import in ES6+.

In the similar way, you can import modules in our app like this for example

```
import { FakeBackend, AuthGuard, ErrorInterceptor } from 'guards';
```

rather than with multiple statements like these for example

```
import { FakeBackend } from 'guards/fake-backend';
import { AuthGuard } from 'guards/auth-guard';
import { FakeBackend } from 'guards/error-interceptor';
```

[MDN Reference](https://%20developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

You can also import modules and give then aliases in import statements e.g

```
import * as PDFMaker from 'JsPdf';
```